# ASP.NET Core Web API returns only one validation error message

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've created an ASP.NET Core SPA application using React as my frontend. I'm trying to display all validation errors, but it seems that only the first error is returned and I don't know why.

Here is my DTO class that contains validation attributes:

```
public class ProductCreateDto
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [MinLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [MinLength(10)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

This is the data that is sent to server:

```
{
    "name": "aav",
    "description": "aa",
    "price": ""
}
```

This is the response from server:

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "00-cc641ad6d94b3947abf9425292a70071-a22e2a3181071947-00",
"errors": {
    "$.price": [
        "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Double. Path: $.price | LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 15."
    ]
}
```

}

As you can see, the errors object does not contains **name** and **description** validation error messages.

Comment: `errors` is an object, it's property `$.price` is an array

Comment: did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not a validation error but a JSON Parsing error. The $.price is actually the JSON path it fails to parse into the field. If the Price member was nullable it would have been parsed. And if the price is required for the Model add the [Required] attribute to it.  I think this is a side effect of the new Microsoft JSON parser.

So I guess your DTO would look something like this.

```
public class ProductCreateDto
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [MinLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [MinLength(10)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    [Required]
    public double? Price { get; set; }
}
```